# Uncertainties about OOP and the struct Keyword

Tags: c++, class, oop, struct

```
class NodeType { 
 public: 
    int info; 
    NodeType* link; 
};
```

I came across this when learning about linked list, and as a beginner, at line 4, pointer `link` is an object of class `NodeType`, this interpretation is definitely wrong, so can somebody please explain what does this line mean? I don't recall learning this when I am interacting with the concept of OOP.

```
struct NodeType 
{ 
    int info; 
    struct NodeType* link; 
};
```

I take that this structure declaration here is of the same as the class declared above, so my second question is, why is there a second `struct` keyword at `line 4`? Can the keyword be removed? Is this the phenomenon called nested struct?

Comment: `link` is a pointer to `NodeType` not an object of type `NodeType`.

Comment: *why is there a second struct keyword at line 4?* either this is C code or the writer is more familiar with C than C++ and doesn't realize that they can leave it out. `Can the keyword be removed?` Yes.

Comment: @Ch3steR Hello and thank you for the response. Hw do I differentiate between the two? Their declaration looks about the same.

Comment: *Is this the phenomenon called nested struct?* No. A nested struct would be a `struct` defined within a `struct`. Eg `struct x { struct y { int z; }; };` `struct NodeType* link; `is merely a variable inside a `struct`.

Comment: How do you differentiate between an object of type `NodeType` and a *pointer* to an object of type `NodeType`?  By the `*` symbol.

Comment: One bit of weirdness you might find is a forward declaration in a `struct`. `struct x { struct y; };`  Note the lack of an identifier after the `struct y`. This means that `struct y` exists, but will be defined later before you need to know what it actually looks like ([and you may never need to know and never get a definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer))

Comment: Since you tagged as `oop`, the `link` is a relationship to a `NodeType` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the two snippets are the same.

> why is there a second struct keyword at line 4?

It's called an *elaborated type specifier* (a type with `struct` prepended to it, or `class`/`union`/`enum`; the definition `class NodeType {}` doesn't count as one).

It's useless here and can be removed. It's only useful when a struct is mentioned for the first time, so the compiler doesn't know it's a struct yet.

In this regard C++ is different from C, where you must prepend `struct` every time to refer to a struct.

> [is] pointer `link` is an object of class `NodeType`?

No, an object of class `NodeType` would be `NodeType link;`, but then it wouldn't be a pointer.

You could say that `link` is an object of type `NodeType *` (a pointer to `NodeType`).

Comment: side note: `struct NodeType link;` (note the lack of `*`) cannot compile as a member of `NodeType` because this would mean `NodeType` contains a `NodeType`, which would contain a `NodeType`, which of course contains a `NodeType`... This goes on forever resulting in a type of infinite size, so the compiler will reject it. There are a couple other reasons it can't work, but this is the fun one. Containing a pointer or reference to itself, that's easy, but containing itself just won't fly.

Comment: Is there an issue having `class NodeType` and a pointer to a `struct NodeType`?  Note that the container is a `class` and the pointer is to a `struct`.  Should the pointer be declared as `class NodeType * link`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think the standard allows mismatching `class` vs `struct`, but MSVC has issues with it, so you shouldn't do it (the two having different effects on mangling).